# Pagination with Javascript Went Wrong

Tags: javascript, pagination

I've coding pagination with JS

out like this

```
<a id="prev">Previous Page</a>
<a id="next">Next Pages</a>
```

and JS Code like this

```
$('#next').click(function(){ 
   var url = window.location.href; 
   var urllen = url.length;
   var cur = parseInt((url.substr(urllen-1)).substr(0,1)); 
   var nurl = url.substr(0,(urllen-1))+(cur+1); 
   if(cur=="NaN") { window.location = (url); } 
   else { window.location = (nurl); } 
}); 
$('#prev').click(function(){ 
   var url = window.location.href; 
   var urllen = url.length; 
   var cur = (url.substr(urllen-1)).substr(0,1); 
   if(cur==1||cur=="NaN") { window.location = (url); } 
   else { var nurl = url.substr(0,(urllen-1))+(cur-1); window.location = (nurl); } 
});
```

and my url like

```
http://localtest/rftpages/record.html?s=1&l=1&bike_id=1
```

let's me explain the reason that i'm using a JavaScript method is i don't want to change my URL that containing page variable that i use in my whole page

so what i'm doing is get all the URL and change bike_id value to next/prev

and the problem is when it count to 19 or URL like

```
http://localtest/rftpages/record.html?s=1&l=1&bike_id=19
```

then i goes next again the URL will become

```
http://localtest/rftpages/record.html?s=1&l=1&bike_id=110
```

any idea/suggestion to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is grab the page from the query string and the either increment or decrements it based on what is clicked.

all you need is this function to get the parameters:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

So if I assume your example:

```
http://localtest/rftpages/record.html?s=1&l=1&bike_id=19
```

Then you can change your function to be:

```
$('#next').on("click", function() {
    var currentPageParameter = getParameterByName("bike_id");
     var s = getParameterByName("s");
     var l = getParameterByName("l");
     var myPage = parseInt(currentPageParameter);
     if (! isNaN(myPage )) {
           myPage = myPage + 1;
           window.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + "?s=" + s + "&l=" + l + "&bike_id=" + myPage;
      }
});
$('#prev').on("click", function() {
 var currentPageParameter = getParameterByName("bike_id");
     var s = getParameterByName("s");
     var l = getParameterByName("l");
     var myPage = parseInt(currentPageParameter);
     if (! isNaN(myPage )) {
           myPage = myPage - 1;
           window.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + "?s=" + s + "&l=" + l + "&bike_id=" + myPage;
      }
});
```